# How to count the number of occurrences of each word in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to read a string from a text file; and to provide a "statistics" about the occurrence of each word using scheme and to provide the most used words.

exp:

```
string = "one two, tree  one two"
```

and getting :

```
one: 2
two: 2
tree: 1
```

I can count each word by using a simple function counter and display the result on the screen, but I can't find a way to use this result to display for example the most 5 used words for example in a huge input text -a book for example-.

update :

Here is my solution for my question but the input should be sorted, like this   (a a a a b b b b b m m m )

```
 (define frequency (lambda(ls) 
           (if (null? ls) '() (freq_aux (car ls) 1 (cdr ls) '() ))))
           (define freq_aux (lambda(l n ls tmp ) ( if(null? ls)
           (cons (cons n l) tmp) (if(equal? l (car ls)) 
           (freq_aux l (+ 1 n) (cdr ls) tmp) 
           (freq_aux (car ls) 1 (cdr ls) (cons (cons n l) tmp))))))
```

Comment: Post the code you've written so far. As a general idea, you could use a hash map for storing the count results (key: word, value: number of occurrences of the word), it'll be simple to find the most common words in there

Comment: The question was asked a while ago; probably can find the answer if you search a bit.

Comment: I give a word frequency program at my blog: http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/03/10/word-frequencies/.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez 
I tried to solve the problem using this code:


(define cout
  (lambda (ls )
    (if (null? ls)
        '(())
        (append (count_aux (car ls) ls 0 '() ) 
                (count (cdr ls))
    
    
    
(define count_aux
  (lambda(l ls n tmp)
    (if(null? (car ls)
       (cons (cons n l) tmp)
       (if(equal? l (car ls) ) (cout_aux l (cdr ls) (+ 1 n) tmp) 
          (count_aux l (cdr ls) n tmp ))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint from another StackOverflow question (I can't find it).

```
(define (tokenize file)
  (with-input-from-file file
    (lambda ()
      (let reading ((lines '()) (words '()) (chars '()))
        (let ((char (read-char)))
          (if (eof-object? char)
              (reverse lines)
              (case char
                ((#\newline) (reading (cons (reverse (cons (reverse chars) words)) lines) '() '()))
                ((#\space)   (reading lines (cons (reverse chars) words) '()))
                (else        (reading lines words (cons char chars))))))))))
```

This returns a list of lines which is a list of words which is a list of characters. You could get a list of strings with:

```
(map list->string (apply append (tokenize <someffile>)))
```

From that:

```
(define (frequency-alist words)
  (let ((alist '()))
    (let scanning ((words words))
      (if (null? words
          alist
          (let ((word (car words)))
            (cond ((assoc word alist)
                   => (lambda (al-item)
                         (set-cdr! al-item (+ 1 (cdr al-item)))))
                  (else (set! alist (cons (cons word 1) alist))))
            (scanning (cdr words)))))))
```

Comment: Here is my solution for my question but the input should be sorted like this :
<blink>
(a a a a b b b b b m m m )
<code>
  (define frequency 
    (lambda(ls)
    (if (null? ls)
        '()
        (freq_aux (car ls) 1 (cdr ls) '() ))))
  

    
    (define freq_aux 
      (lambda(l n ls tmp )
      ( if(null? ls)
          (cons (cons n l) tmp)
          (if(equal? l (car ls))  (freq_aux l (+ 1 n) (cdr ls) tmp)
                     (freq_aux (car ls) 1 (cdr ls) (cons (cons n l) tmp))))))</blink>